# How to use object literals in TS to replace complex switch cases?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following scenario: In a switch, I call two different functions based on the case.
The first function has args "A" and "B" which are numbers and the second function has an arg "C" which is a string.

Now I am wondering if it is possible to convert this switch statement into an object literal.

My TS code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  result: string = null;
  v: number = 1;

  firstFn(a: number, b: number) {
    console.log(1);
    if (a == undefined && b == undefined) return 'missingParam';
    return a == b ? 'Equal' : 'Not';
  }

  secondFn(c: string) {
    console.log(2);
    return c ? c : 'noParam';
  }

  doStuff() {
    const opt = {
      0: this.firstFn.apply(this, [1, 1]),
      1: this.secondFn.apply(this, ['k']),
    };

    this.result = opt[this.v];

    //Toggle between the two functions
    this.v == 1 ? this.v-- : this.v++;
  }
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<button (click)="doStuff()">Do stuff</button>

{{ result }}
```

Here is my attempt in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-kq1nrx

The problem that I am facing is that now when I call the "doStuff()" function both functions attached to the properties of the object are calculated instead of just the one that is selected. (You can check that by checking the console in stackblitz)

Is there a way to avoid this double function call?
If yes how?

Comment: `.apply` _calls_ the function, then you put the _results_ in the `opt` object.

Comment: Aaah yes I completely missed it. If I use bind then it works! Thank you!

Comment: If this is a personal project and you are doing this for learning purposes, then fair enough. If anyone else other than you is going to read this code, then I'd strongly recommend against doing this kind of thing. Simpler is better.

Comment: @BenWainwright I just wanted to see so I can pick a preference. There is no real application right now :)

Comment: "*convert this switch statement into an object literal*" - I don't see a `switch` statement in the code you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to substitute `.apply()` with `.bind()`. Bind does not invoke the function so it does not trigger the two logs.

Also, note that now you should invoke the function when you get the reference:

`this.result = opt[this.v]();`

Updated code:

```
  doStuff() {
    const opt = {
      0: this.firstFn.bind(this, [1, 1]),
      1: this.secondFn.bind(this, ['k']),
    };

    this.result = opt[this.v]();

    //Toggle between the two functions
    this.v == 1 ? this.v-- : this.v++;
  }
```